# How to use an Excel formula to obtain the best match based on the wording within the same cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I need to find the exact matching case between two Excel data tables. While working on it, I have searched through most of the websites.
[Exact Match 001](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-match-case-sensitive/)
During this process, I have tried various functions such as VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929), [Index Match](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/look-up-values-with-vlookup-index-or-match-68297403-7c3c-4150-9e3c-4d348188976b). However, in all cases, I couldn't compare two separate words within the same cell.

Next, I attempted to separate the words using the [TEXTSPLIT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7) function and tried to count them using the [Search](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/search-function-f79ef0b8-0991-4fc1-93b0-627f019a69e3) and COUNTIF fucntion. Unfortunately, I didn't find a proper solution for this.

I require expert support to write a formula that retrieves the best case number from Table 01, using the data from Table 02.

For more clarity, please refer to the link of the [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_P7wm3D0HKA1yaDerbSB5Y6n7_dvkzehMji3Nfo4uOE/edit?usp=sharing) as well.

Best regard
Indika

Table 01

[image: Table 01]

Table 02

[image: Table 02]

Expecting Solution

[image: Solution]

Comment: Do you know how to write VBA?

Comment: Your title says *Excel formula* but you've tagged with `google-sheets`. Please, use the right tags.

Comment: Why no best case for 'CDE CAB' and 'YHY YYY XXX', I mean, there is definitely a match for at least one of the substrings in these values, just like there was for 'ABC BCD'? Is it so that the numbers can only be used once?

Comment: Best suit solution will be a Excel or G-Sheet formula but If you have the VBA solution that also Great.

Comment: Actually my data is bit long , so there may be a base case and may be not as well, but if we have best case I need to capture Number as best case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite intricate, but here are my two cents to find the *best* match using Excel ms365:

[image]

Formula in `B3`:

```
=MAP(A3:A7,LAMBDA(s,REDUCE("",D3:D6,LAMBDA(x,y,LET(fit,MMULT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" "&A3:A7," ",SEQUENCE(,99))," ")&" "," "&y&" ")),SEQUENCE(99,,,0)),IF(ROW(s)-2=XMATCH(MAX(fit),fit),LET(z,VLOOKUP(y,D3:E6,2,0),IF(x="",z,IF(COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(y," "))<COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(XLOOKUP(x,E3:E6,D3:D6)," ")),z,x))),x))))))
```

The idea here is that we iterate all values under 'Data 01' using `MAP()`. Each iteration, using the 's' variable, we have a nested `REDUCE()`. The idea behind this nested function is to find out if 's' is the best fit for one of the values under 'Data02'.

To find out what is the best fit I applied two things:

- I checked how many substrings (split by space) each value under 'Data01' actually has compared to each value under 'Data02'. This is done by the `MMULT()` function. If the current row indeed holds the most substrings available in any of the values under 'Data02' then take the number;
- `REDUCE()` will loop all the values under 'Data02' to test the above for all strings. If it so happened that 's' is the best fit for multiple values under 'Data02' then this is now able to check if the next value is made up of less substrings. My assumption here: ***fewer substrings (split by space) == a better fit!***.